# SVM prediction for large amount of data

Tags: r, machine-learning, classification, svm, libsvm

I want to run a SVM classification (with binary response) for relatively large amount of data (150M). So, I sampled a training dataset (Say about 50,000) and built the model using `svm{e1071}` in `R`. Now I want to apply the result to the entire dataset. I don't have any idea how to load and run such a large dataset in `R`. So, what I need is to extract the model parameters from `R` and run it in another platform. In other words, I want to get the same `weight.svm` (probabilities) for the entire data:

```
model.svm = svm(as.factor(response) ~.,data=predictors, probability=TRUE) 
predict.svm= predict(model.svm,predictors,probability=TRUE)
weight.svm = data.frame(attr(predict.svm,"probabilities"))
```

Any suggestion? Any simple text/reference to show how this predict function works in SVM? Which values should I extract from the `model.svm` object e.g. `model.svm$SV` etc.?

Comment: You might want to investigate PMML: https://support.zementis.com/entries/21197842-PMML-Export-Functionality-in-R-Supported-Packages . I have no history with this company and cannot vouch for it, but it claims to be able to export the structure of various models and then do predictions with them.

Answer (score 0):

If your kernel is linear you would can use the [Pegasos algorithm](http://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s10107-010-0420-4#/page-1). You can find the algorithm in Page 7 of the paper, it is less than 10 lines of code and is one of the fastest algorithms for solving the SVM optimization problem.